# Dreamweaver CC (2015) - Disable auto selecting of code in Code Inspector from clicking an area on Live View

Tags: dreamweaver

I have noticed when I click on an area in the Live View, it will select the corresponding chunk of code in the Code Inspector...

This seems to happen at random times as well, not just when I want it to. I will be working on code and suddenly my screen will jump to another section and highlight it. Very frustrating!

I have View > Code View Options > Highlight Invalid Code unchecked

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try View > Live View Options > Highlight Changes in Live Code and make sure it's unchecked?

View > Code View Options > Highlight Invalid Code should only source turn code yellow when it may be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

This will help, try VIEW >> LIVE VIEW OPTIONS >> HIDE LIVE VIEW DISPLAYS

And I really hope that when they redesign the next version they do not get another interior decorator who has never used ANY abobe products to have any say in anything.